# Run .Net Core Console App From API Using Process.Start On Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, process

My requirement is, using .Net Core API --> Run .Net Core Console APP Via Process.Start

I read many articles but they provide only 50% answer.
If you know then please kindly suggest.

When some user hit that .Net Core AP , then internally they run one .Net Console App using `Process.Start`.

Comment: Running commands using `Process.Start` from an API is almost always a terrible idea. Why do you need this?

Comment: I agree with @DavidG. The reason you don't get good answers from articles is because it's not a common practice, and those who do this probably don't know of better solutions. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Start & Stop Background Service  In Ubuntu As a Server i.e. Required one Service To Fetch Data From Other API. If I use API For Same Thing Then my Front End Is Very Slow .So I think Create One Separate Console App & Start/Stop Via Process.Start When servie start then they fetch data

Comment: If You have Any Other Idea Then Please Kindly Suggest.  Note --> Volume Of Data Is Very High +1000 K